# How do I capitalize the first letter in every paragraph when there are multiple paragraphs in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, replace, capitalization, capitalize

So I have lists where one cell in each line will have either a paragraph or multiple paragraphs. I need to standardize these so they're in sentence case. I've built some code to do this that works if there's a single paragraph, but when there are multiple paragraphs, or line breaks, in the cell, it fails to capitalize that first letter. I've tried doing a find and replace with the Line break itself as a variable, but that doesn't work and I've gotten stuck.

Most of my code works by converting the entire selected range to Lcase and then doing a series of find and replace to make the first letter of each sentence capitalized.

```
Selection.Replace What:=". a", Replacement:=". A"
```

I go through the entire alphabet, than do it again with "! a" and "~? a"

But this technique won't work if there's a Line break between the previous paragraph and a new one.

When it's done I use a range selection to capitalize the first letter in each cell, but I'm not sure how relevant that is.

```
For Each cell In RNG
cell.Value = UCase(Left(cell.Value, 1)) & Right(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 1)
Next cell
```

Thanks again to Scott Craner for his answer!

```
Selection.Replace What:=Chr(10) & "A"
```

This solves my problem!

Comment: did you try the `StrConv(string,vbProperCase)`?

Comment: Please define what do you understand by 'paragraph` in an Excel cell. A new row on that specific cell? Obtained after pressing Alt + Enter?

Comment: `What:= Chr(10) & "a"`

Comment: Scott Craner, This worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub testProperCaseParagraph()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arr As Variant, rng As Range, cel As Range
  Dim El As Variant, strProp As String

  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
  Set rng = sh.Range("A14:B22") 'use here your range (I used it for testing purpose)
    For Each cel In rng
        arr = Split(cel.value, vbLf)
        For Each El In arr
            If strProp = "" and El <> "" Then
                strProp = UCase(left(El, 1)) & Right(El, Len(El) - 1)
            ElseIf El <> "" Then
                strProp = strProp & vbLf & UCase(left(El, 1)) & Right(El, Len(El) - 1)
            End If
        Next
        cel.value = strProp: strProp = ""
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm afraid this keeps getting stuck with a "Run time error 5: Invalid procedure or argument" It does so on this part     strProp = strProp & vbLf & UCase(Left(El, 1)) & Right(El, Len(El) - 1)

Comment: What value does `El` variable show when you move the cursor over it, then the code stops on error? Is it possible to have `vbLf` followed by anything at the end of the string? I mean, you pressed Alt + Enter and did not input any string...

Comment: @MRDoubleyou: I adapted the code to also accept such cases (an empty row paragraph) . Please refresh the page and try the code again.

Comment: OK. I did not think before, that such cases of empty paragraphs will exist... Glad being able to help you! But, if it answers your question, ticking the check box to the code left side will make it the accepted answer. In this way, if somebody else looks for a similar solution, he will know which answer was accepted...

Answer (score 1):

I would try an approach with RegEx to give you more flexibility in the future if needed:

```
Sub LoopCellFormat()

For Each cell In RNG
cell.Value = StandardPar(Cell.Value)
Next cell

End Sub

Function StandardPar(ByVal txt As String) As String
 Dim m As Object
 txt = LCase(txt)

 txt = Application.Replace(txt, 1, 1, UCase(Left$(txt, 1)))
 Debug.Print txt

 With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
 .Pattern = "[!\?\.][\s\n\r]+."
 .Global = True
 For Each m In .Execute(txt)

 txt = Application.Replace(txt, m.FirstIndex + 1, m.Length, UCase(m.Value))

 Next

 End With
 StandardPar = txt

End Function
```

To use RegEx you should set the reference in the VBA Editor:

[image]

Comment: Wow, this works really well. I'm not sure how a regular expression works or what it's doing, but this is definitely functional.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on track. For this example, cell `A1` contains multiple paragraphs...

```
Sub ParagraphsCapitalize()

    Dim p&, s$

    s = [a1]

    p = InStr(s, vbLf)
    If p Then Mid(s, p + 1, 1) = UCase(Mid(s, p + 1, 1))

    Debug.Print s

End Sub
```

---

Here I fleshed it out for you...

```
Sub Test()

    MsgBox ParagraphCaps([a1])

End Sub



Function ParagraphCaps$(s$)

    Dim p&
    Do
        p = InStr(p + 1, s, vbLf)
        If p Then Mid(s, p + 1, 1) = UCase(Mid(s, p + 1, 1))
    Loop While p
    Mid(s, 1, 1) = UCase(Mid(s, 1, 1))

    ParagraphCaps = s

End Function
```

Comment: I was able to get the fleshed out version you put here working, but when I tried to add this to my existing code I it wasn't doing anything?

Comment: Please select an answer.